# How to use a pivot in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

use three tables (TB_HOPE_INDUSTRY, TB_M_INDUSTRY, TB_PROFILE),
I want to get a red outline table.

How can I make a sql query?
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating the query by clicking the _Query Design_ button and selecting _Crosstab_ in the Design Ribbon?  Could you have a read of [MCVE] please.

Comment: Start with a query that joins tables and pulls relevant fields then click CROSSTAB on the query design tab.

Comment: Note about CROSSTAB:  A pivot table often implies a live, dynamic report where different statistics can be viewed and obtained by interactively selecting different data columns and aggregate functions, and sometimes with the ability to drill down into data via subreports.  A CROSSTAB only provides a single, static view of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a query that uses all 3 tables, and

- Join TB_PROFILE and TB_HOPE_INDUSTRY on both PROFILE_ID fields.
- Join TB_M_INDUSTRY and TB_HOPE_INDUSTRY on both INDUSTRY_CD fields
- SELECT the columns PROFILE_ID and NAME from table TB_PROFILE
- Add the column INDUSTRY_NO from table TB_HOPE_INDUSTRY
- Add the column INDUSTRY_NAME from table TB_M_INDUSTRY
- Click CROSSTAB on the ribbon

Then, define the following settings fot the *Function* and *Crosstab* properties in the design grid:

- group by PROFILE_ID and INDUSTRY_NO
- select the *First* function for the columns NAME and INDUSTRY_NAME
- change the name of the NAME column to something like PROFILE
- Display PROFILE as row header, INDUSTRY_NO as column header, (first of) INDUSTRY_NAME as value.
- Do not display PROFILE_ID (just use it for grouping)

The resulting SQL query should be something like this:

```
TRANSFORM First(TB_M_INDUSTRY.INDUSTRY_NAME) AS FirstOfINDUSTRY_NAME
SELECT First(TB_PROFILE.NAME) AS PROFILE
FROM TB_PROFILE INNER JOIN 
    (TB_M_INDUSTRY INNER JOIN TB_HOPE_INDUSTRY ON TB_M_INDUSTRY.INDUSTRY_CD = TB_HOPE_INDUSTRY.INDUSTRY_CD)
  ON TB_PROFILE.PROFILE_ID = TB_HOPE_INDUSTRY.PROFILE_ID
GROUP BY TB_PROFILE.NAME
PIVOT TB_HOPE_INDUSTRY.INDUSTRY_NO;
```